# Problems with position: fixed and z-index not working properly

Tags: html, css, z-index, fixed, parallax

**Solution**
To fix the problem I ended up using a split solution: one set of instructions for Chrome/Firefox/IE (modern versions) and one for iOS/Mac Safari.

I did this through a CSS Browser Selector javascript code:
http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

---

Here's the page I am working on:

http://www.panamavota.com

The homepage is a vertical one-page website, and I am trying to create a little bit of a parallax effect where the content slides over the image and "landing-page" links and text as you scroll down.

This is the basic html structure:

```
<div id="home">
  ...
</div>
<div id="content1">
  ...
</div>
<div id="content2">
  ...
</div>
```

I want the content inside #home to stay fixed with the background as you scroll, and all the content of #content1,2,3, etc. to slide over the contents of #home div.

I can't seem to manage to get it working consistently. I've managed to get it working on Safari, but it would then break down for no reason whatsoever.. it seems to work fine in Chrome right now…

---

**Update 1:**
As noted in a comment below, it seems to be working in Chrome and Firefox. Safara iOS gives me spotty results, and Safari for Mac OS doesn't seem to work.

**Update 2:**
It seems that adding a negative z-index to the fixed div fixed the issue across most browsers (at least their most current versions).

*Also keep in mind that you must assign a position value to divs to make sure the z-index property works.*

Comment: Could you add a description how it breaks? I don't have a Mac here, so I can't test, but I would try giving a negative z-index to the fixed div.

Comment: The text shows over the colored content divs below. On iPhone it will sometimes show and sometimes be underneath when I scroll up and down which makes no sense why it would do that.

Comment: That worked! It also seems to work on Chrome and Firefox for mac. I will test on a PC later today to make sure it works.

Comment: @MrLister That works, but I got a different problem now.. giving the fixed div a negative z-index pushes it behind the body element? My links are dead now...

Comment: Then I don't know. I can't reproduce the original problem here, so there's nothing I can suggest. You're right about the negative z-index though, so that's not the solution. By the way, what does `.safari #landing {position: relative}` mean?

Comment: @MrLister the .safari is a hack I found online that makes those instructions only apply to Safari. It works with jQuery.

Comment: http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

Comment: **It does not require jQuery**